# How to upload attendance sheet in attendance table from Excel sheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a payroll, I want to upload employee attendance sheet from an Excel sheet.

Excel sheet is like this

```
EmpId   Date   Intime   Out Time
--------------------------

1     2/2/2012  09:00   18:00  
1     6/2/2012  09:00   18:00  
1     8/2/2012  09:00   18:00  
1     9/2/2012  09:00   18:00
```

Entry for all this record is simple. But could you guys please help me how to make entry for missing dates in this month (keeping in mind things like if it is Sunday or government holiday then marks it present)

How can we implement this?

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: It might be something like: (1) Get the data from Excel to the DataTable first, (2) Loop through the records while looking for missing sequence in dates, (3) add records with appropriate status for holidays and sundays, (4) send the datatable for update in the data source.

Comment: for government and other holidays you may maintain a separate table and check every missing date (other than Sundays) in that table.

Comment: No i think i have to do it , when uploading excel sheet not after that because in that case there will be duplicacy in dates.

Comment: Right. ** You may also set a unique key in the employee attendance table (on employee id + date). That way the server will return an exception that you could handle gracefully. ** Alternatively, you may first check the minimum and maximum dates for each employee from excel and search for if any record exist with the same date in the data source, to intimate the user for expected loss of relevant excel entries. Think about all scenarios first.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Read Data from Excel Sheet and Fill in Dataset

Step 2: Make a Loop to check the number missing days

Step 3: Check whether the missing day is sunday or Govt Holiday ( To check sunday ,In .net

dayisweek is available)

Step 4:According to that, modify dataset

Step 5: save dataset to database